# Передача числа с устройства на компьютер

Tags: автоматизация, схемотехника

Проще будет через пример описать.
Допустим есть электронный градусник, который на своём табле показывает некоторое число. Ну и собственно нужно получить это число и перенести его автоматически, допустим, в форму на сайте на ПК по клику кнопки.
Где можно про такое почитать, и что мне вообще нужно искать, чтобы разобраться?

Comment: например: Термометр на Arduino, если нужно распознавать числа с градусника (нет возможности связаться с ПК), то OpenCV

Comment: В смысле нет возможности связаться с ПК? Задача как раз таки в том, чтобы с устройства, которое выдаёт на своём экране какое-то число (не обязательно это градусник) перенести это число на ПК в форму в браузере.

Comment: в смысле, если у датчика нет интерфейса для взаимодействия с ПК

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж речь про сайт, то я бы посоветовал взять [ENC28J60 Ethernet](https://aliexpress.ru/wholesale?catId=&SearchText=ENC28J60%20Ethernet) модуль. По факту в нём реализован http сервер, контент для которого ты генерируешь сам динамически, из своего кода, который зашиваешь в ардуину. Реализуй api и пользуйся им.

Если же надо ардуино-компутер напрямую, то можно и com. Просто напиши "сервер" (код для ардуино), "клиент" (для PC), объяви общую структуру данных с полями конечной длинны и пересылай эту структуру прямо "как есть".
Структура:

```cpp
struct alignas(8) SStats
{
  uint16_t someint;
  bool somebool;
};
```

Arduino:

```cpp
SStats incoming;
if(Serial.readBytes((char *)&incoming, data_size) == data_size)
{
    dosomething(incoming);
}
```

PC:

```cpp
SStats outgoing;
fillData(&outgoing);
serial->write(&outgoing, sizeof(SStats));
```

Comment: Ну речь не то, чтобы про сайт. Информационная система через браузер, у которой доступа в интернет не будет вообще, и не нужен он ей.

Comment: Ну так proxy_pass делай в ардуину... Или у тебя ардуина будет не в той-же сети, что и веб-сервер?